# Better alternative for readonly information in input box

Tags: readability, intuition

I have this form where the topmost row (File #, Patient & Med.Aid) is readonly. Input boxes in this row are readonly and the cursor turns to
"banned" icon on hovering those fields. I can't find a better way to organize this information without clutter and in a way that matches with the second row.

[image]

I would like to know the following.

1. Is it intuitive enough and user friendly to present readonly information in input boxes?
2. Is there a better way to show the information in the first row without using readonly input boxes and without losing readability?

Comment: If information is read only, why use an input box at all? Wouldn't it make more sense to use a simple text (label) for read only information?

Comment: I was wondering if it's gonna mess up the alignment with the second row. maybe I must use label or div with border and padding same the input boxes?

Comment: I'm with André - if the user is never to edit these field don't make them read only. Remember the form-follows-function principle. Labels will also have less constraints, so for instance, you can make the text slightly bigger. Your problem is that of visual design, not of readonly.

Comment: @icoder8898 It won't mess with the alignment if you give it the same padding and margins as the input boxes. But I agree with André, that would be best.

Comment: @André lzhaki Mike thanks guys for the feedback. I have decided to replace the input boxes with labels but with the same width as the input fields in the second row. Will also remove the white background to make it look more "readonly".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you *could* use labels instead if you wanted to, but that involves adding CSS to style the labels to mimic the other rows or to style them any other way.  Leaving them readonly requires you to use CSS to show that you shouldn't focus the inputs.

The *simplest* thing to do is also the *easiest* thing to do:

**Use the *`disabled`* property**.

This is exactly what it was designed for.  Disabled elements **do not allow focus**, whereas readonly elements do, so no CSS needed.  Disabled elements **do not get sent** when the form is submitted, whereas readonly elements do, so less overhead there.

Using the disabled property allows you to maintain your input styling, while at the same time, since the elements are disabled, it shows users that the fields are inputs that have already been supplied and that they are not editable.

I've created a jsFiddle that demonstrates this. Here's a screen shot:

[image: jsfiddle demo screen shot]

### ***[See the jsFiddle demo in action](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/CHRJv/)***

Comment: The problem with this is that default styles for disabled tend to have grey text which is harder to read.  There are also semantic issues -- disabled implies "not applicable"/"not available" which is different from read-only.

Comment: @AmeliaBR - I simply disagree. I think this is being overthought.  This is the easiest and simplest solution to the question asked.  If you really care about the _grey_ text, you can easily augment it with CSS.  That said, I don't think it's hard to read at all.

Comment: @CodeMaverick thanks for the feedback. It doesn't necessarily have to be input boxes. I was even thinking if there is a better way to show these readonly information in the top row. I couldn't find a better way to arrange this information other than in the same layout as in the second row. I found that if we have 2 different layout and alignment for the 2 rows, it affects the readability. What do you think?

Comment: @CodeMaverick Just an FYI your example link is dead.

Comment: @Dan Updated link. I had changed usernames awhile back.

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle for how it should look  --  http://jsfiddle.net/DaveAlger/CHRJv/1/  --  if there is ever a time when those fields could be edited then show the inputs in the disabled state as @CodeMaverick suggests.  **if they will never be editable then show them as labels.**

Comment: Don't use the `disabled` attribute. It prevents screen readers from having access to those fields. Use the `readonly` attribute instead and use CSS to style fields with that attribute.

Answer (score -1):

**If you have to use an `input` field for this...**

```
<input type="text" name="input-name" id="input-id" onfocus="blur()">
```

This will prevent visitors from clicking and typing in the input field. Then just apply a style to differentiate from other `input` fields such as:-

```
background: #C7C7C7;
```

I think this is probably the best way to users so it is clear that the `input` fields are not usable.

**If you don't have to use an `input` field for this...**

Just use `<div>` instead and style them similar to your `input` fields so they look like part of the table still.

Comment: This would be a Stackoverflow answer, this is a UX site where we answer the question from the POV of the user (by citing surveys and sources), not post the code to do the question asked.

Comment: Just to add, your answer would be fine if you posted WHY they should do it this way. What benefit does it give the user compared to how it is now?

Comment: Hi Mike, I actually did post more than that (or attempted to) but have realised it isn't there any longer. Oops. I'll extend my answer again, thanks.

Comment: If you expand on your answer and say why it is better than André's solution (his comment on the question), then I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @GeoffJackson thanks a lot for the feedback. It doesn't have to be input boxes. It doesn't even have to follow the same layout and alignment as in the second row. Just that I was struggling to find a better way to display this information in a user friendly way that conforms to the general layout.

Comment: @Code Maverick did a better job of explaining what I was getting at with my answer.